How to show a hover message on a disabled toggle button in Dash?
I'm working on a Dash application where I have a toggle button (dbc.Switch) that gets disabled based on the user's input. I would like to display a hover tooltip message when the toggle button is disabled. However, I noticed that the tooltip doesn't appear when the button is disabled. Here's the code I'm using:
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
from dash import Dash, html, dcc, Input, Output

app = Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP])

app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        dcc.Input(id='number-input', type='number', placeholder='Enter a number'),
        dbc.Switch(
            id="toggle-button",
            label="Toggle Button",
            style={"display": "inline-block", "margin-right": "10px"}
        ),
        dbc.Tooltip(
            id="toggle-tooltip",
            target="toggle-button",
            placement="top"
        ),
    ]
)

@app.callback(
    Output("toggle-button", "disabled"),
    Output("toggle-tooltip", "children"),
    Input("number-input", "value")
)
def update_toggle(number):
    if number is not None and number % 2 == 0:
        return False, "Disabled for even numbers"
    else:
        return True, "This is a toggle button"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)

The toggle-button gets disabled when the input number is even, and I would like the toggle-tooltip to display a message explaining why it's disabled this should be come when i hover on toggle. The tooltip should still be visible when hovering over the disabled button.

The tooltip won't show up if its target is disabled.
One way to fix this is to wrap the "toggle-button" switch into a component and use that component as the tooltip target, eg.
app = Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP])

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Input(id='number-input', type='number', placeholder='Enter a number'),
    html.Span(id='toggle-button-wrapper', children=[
        dbc.Switch(
            id="toggle-button",
            label="Toggle Button",
            style={"display": "inline-block", "margin-right": "10px"}
        )
    ]),
    dbc.Tooltip(
        id="toggle-tooltip",
        target="toggle-button-wrapper",
        placement="top"
    )
])

@app.callback(
    Output("toggle-button", "disabled"),
    Output("toggle-tooltip", "children"),
    Input("number-input", "value")
)
def update_toggle(number):
    if number is not None and number % 2 == 0:
        return True, "Disabled for even numbers"
    else:
        return False, "This is a toggle button"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)

NB. Since you want to disable the button when the input number is even, I inverted the return values for the button disabled property.

If you don't want to use a wrapper, another way to fix this is to control the tooltip with a callback :

The tooltip's visibility can be controlled with callbacks much like a
Popover component. Simply set the desired value of is_open in a
callback. If you are manually controlling the value of is_open, you
may wish to also set trigger=None. By default the Tooltip will show
when the target element is hovered or focused.


Thanks this works for me @EricLavault
